# Why inline-block can not be vertically aligned

Tags: css

I am pretty new to CSS display, currently I want to center align some text and icon(vertically), but it just not works:

```css
.header {
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #1f78b4;
}
.holder {
width:auto;
height: 30px;
background-color: lightblue;
float:right;
line-height: 30px;
}
.menuitem {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 30px;
}
.source {
height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TEST COSMOS ICONS</title>
 <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/qRRrqNRQJ2GCtUGjRFh7DM/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <span class="holder">
   <span class="menuitem source">Perf</span>
   <span class="menuitem icon-gear"></span>
   <span class="menuitem icon-download"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought a line 100% line height can control the text and inline-block elements vertically align center, but if you pay a specify attention to those icon, they are a little above the center.

Comment: [perhaps this will help you](http://howtocenterincss.com), though I'm aware that is doesn't really "teach"

Answer (score 0):

"Why inline-block can not be vertically aligned?"

The point of `in-line` is to have elements be propagated to the screen from left-to-right; so, horizontally.

If you want it vertically, *don't* use elements styled with `in-line` because the elements naturally propagate from top to bottom; so, vertically.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:middle` seems to be what you are after but you need to apply it to the pseudo-elements too.

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1f78b4;
}
.holder {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.menuitem,
.menuitem::before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.source {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST COSMOS ICONS</title>
  <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/qRRrqNRQJ2GCtUGjRFh7DM/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <span class="holder">
    <span class="menuitem source">Perf</span>
    <span class="menuitem icon-gear"></span>
    <span class="menuitem icon-download"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when run it, there is still not same space above and below the icon, this can tell from that gear icon, the top area is larger than bottom area

Comment: That's due to the actual character glyphs being used.